# Is search and replace the only way to rename an asp control in the code behind file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, refactoring

Is search and replace the only way to rename as asp control in the code behind file?
I find this extremely annoying, but it is the only way I can find.

Scenario:

I'll find a variable that needs renaming (Usually to meet naming convention)
I'll rename the variable in the aspx/ascx file.
I'll have to go in the code behind files and search and replace.
I get annoyed

Are there any better ways - preferably that would not touch a similarly named variable in another scope in the project.

I'm on VS2008 with resharper -- does VS2010 address this perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DevExpress Refactor](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/) will propagate your renames from codebehind to markup and vice-versa.